# Last n elements of an EventSeries

Tags: time-series

Is there a simple way to take an `EventSeries` (in my case quarterly GDP) and get a new `EventSeries` consisting of say the last $n$ entries?

This works:

```
v = GDPQ["ValueList"][[1]];
t = GDPQ["DateList"][[1]];
recdentGDPQ = EventSeries[v[[-11 ;;]], {t[[-11 ;;]]}];
```

But this does not:

```
recentGDPQ = GDPQ[[-11;;]]
```

Is there a simple expression to do this?

Comment: perhaps [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesWindow.html) might be helpful

Comment: `EventSeries[GDPQ["Path"][[-11;;]]]`?

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly possible to obtain *GDP* (quarterly or annual) in an `EventSeries` nevertheless it seems as slightly counter-intuitive; in what follows we'll use annual *GDP* figures as returned by evaluating `y=CountryData["USA", {{"GDP"}, {1950, 2018}}]`; please note that `y` is a `TimeSeries` object, therefore we'll first turn it into an `EventSeries` and then we'll obtain its last eg `10` entries.

In the following code segment, I strip away the `Quantity` unit and keep only the magnitude from the values but that's just a personal preference; it is not essential to do that for the purpose of this answer.

```
gdp = EventSeries[QuantityMagnitude[y["Values"]], {y["Times"]}]
```

Next, using `TimeSeriesWindow`, we can obtain the desired sample:

```
DateListPlot[{
  TimeSeriesWindow[gdp, {Automatic, AbsoluteTime["1994"]}], 
  TimeSeriesWindow[gdp, {AbsoluteTime["1995"], Automatic}]
  },
 PlotLabel -> "US Annual GDP",
 PlotLegends -> (
   Row[Riffle[#, "-"]] & /@ MapAt[
     Reverse,
     Transpose[{
       DateString[#, {"Year"}] & /@ 
        Through[{First, Last}[gdp["Times"]]],
       {1994, 1995}}
      ], 2])]
```

> [image: Blockquote]